# When URLConnection timeout occurs, need to try connecting two more times before changing the url and trying again

Tags: java, exception, connection, urlconnection

I need to try connecting to url in the string `request_url`. If connection timeout occurs, I need to retry 2 more times before calling another url (`ans.getUrl(2)`) and repeat the same logic. Here is my code snippet. Can anyone help me out on the logic I need to be using here?

```
        //ans.getUrl returns a url based on the int parameter you send. It can only be 1 and 2.
       String request_url= ans.getUrl(1);
        try {
                    URL url;
                    URLConnection urlConn;
                    DataInputStream input;

                    //URL Creation:
                    url = new URL(request_url);


                    // URL connection channel.
                    urlConn = url.openConnection();

                    urlConn.setConnectTimeout(2000);

                    urlConn.setDoInput(true);

                    urlConn.setDoOutput(true);

                    urlConn.setUseCaches(false);



                    // Get response data.


                    input = new DataInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream());

                    String str;
                    System.out.println("Response XML::: ");

                    while (null != ((str = input.readLine()))) {
                        System.out.println("XML:: "+str);
                        //Write to temp file for parsing
                        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("response.xml", true);
                        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                        out.write(str+"\n");
                        //Close the output stream
                        out.close();

                    }
                    //Close input
                    input.close();


                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: "
                            + e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Caught IOException: "
                            + e.getMessage());
                }
```

Comment: You may not need to do this at all. Under the hood, the underlying TCP socket will already have done at least 3 connection attempts before the exception is thrown. Were you aware of that?

Comment: no. I was not. Thanks. I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the whole bit of code you posted in a function, and then apply the retry loop around that function. You'll need to allow the connect exception to propogate out to do this.